# How to select number columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I select number columns in the below column names

```
output_df.columns =  Index(['EVENT_ID', 'Date', 'Time', 'Track', '#', 'Distance', 'Betfair Grade','Runners', 'Win Trap', 'Win BSP', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
       '8', '9', '10', 'Trap1 Odds Band', 'Trap2 Odds Band', 'Trap3 Odds Band'],
      dtype='object')
```

I tried this function and I got the below output.

```
output_df.filter(regex="\d+", axis=1).columns

Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Trap1 Odds Band',
       'Trap2 Odds Band', 'Trap3 Odds Band'],dtype='object')
```

I just want the number columns:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Comment: `output_df.filter(regex="^\d+$", axis=1).columns`, otherwise any number containing column will match

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering a dataframe by column name based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228145/filtering-a-dataframe-by-column-name-based-on-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering a full match:

```
output_df.filter(regex="^\d+$", axis=1).columns
```

Or better without `filter`:

```
df.columns[df.columns.isdigit()]
```

Comment: It worked as intended

Comment: @ChukypedroOkolie Oh great! Even added another version.

Answer (score 4):

```
new_df = df[df.columns.isnumeric()]
```

This should work?