# Pandas Filtering Column

Tags: python, pandas

Following up on the accepted answer at another question on SO ([Filtering a dataframe by column name based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228145/filtering-a-dataframe-by-column-name-based-on-multiple-conditions)):

```
import pandas as pd

c = ["XYYZ 1011", "XYYZ 1021", "XYYZ 1031", "XXYZ 1011", "XXYZ 1021", "XXYZ 1031","XYY 1001", "XYY 1002", "XXZ 1001"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=c)
print(df)

df = df.filter(regex='X[XY|YY]Z 10[1|2|3]1')
print(df)
```

The output of print misses XXYZ 1011, XXYZ 1021, XXYZ 1031 etc column Why?

Comment: Should be `regex='X(XY)|(YY)Z 10[1|2|3]1'`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, your regex should be `'X(XY|YY)Z 10[123]1'`:

```
df.filter(regex='X(XY|YY)Z 10[123]1')
```

output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [XYYZ 1011, XYYZ 1021, XYYZ 1031, XXYZ 1011, XXYZ 1021, XXYZ 1031]
Index: []
```

You have to differentiate characters groups `[123]` -> one "1 or 2 or 3" character, and alternative patterns `(ABC|DEF)` the string `ABC` or `DEF`

Comment: Yes, should work